# How to create an ArrayData or InternalRow given a StructType as Schema in SparkSQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When defining an UDT in SparkSQL, I make a UDT like this

```
class trajUDT extends UserDefinedType[traj] {
  override def sqlType: DataType = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("id", DataTypes.StringType),
    StructField("loc", ArrayType(StructType(Seq(
      StructField("x",DataTypes.DoubleType),
      StructField("y",DataTypes.DoubleType)
    ))))
 ))
 ...
 }
```

where traj is a Class

```
class traj(val id:UTF8String,val loc:Array[Tuple2[Double,Double]] )
```

and I want to write a serialize funtion like this

```
override def serialize(p: traj): GenericInternalRow = {
  new GenericInternalRow(Array[Any](p.id,p.loc.map(x=>Array(x._1,x._2)))
}
```

But it failed as it told me that this cannot be convert to a ArrayData.

I also write a deserialize function like this:

```
override def deserialize(datum: Any): traj = {
  val arr=datum.asInstanceOf[InternalRow]
  val id = arr.getUTF8String(0)
  val xytype=StructType(Seq(
    StructField("x",DataTypes.DoubleType),
    StructField("y",DataTypes.DoubleType)
  ))
  val xy = arr.getArray(1)
  val xye =xy.toArray[Tuple2[Double,Double]](xytype)
  new traj(id,xye)
}
```

And I guess it could also not work...

So can someone teach me how to do these two conversion?

Comment: may I ask why are you trying to define such type? have you tried using spark native types?

Comment: @shay__  As you can see , i just want a class to represent the "trajectory", so i can then define some methods on it? And I think using an UDT seems to be more beautiful than reading the raw data and converting it to the trajecotry Class by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem while working with `InternalRow`

Constructing an `InternalRow` with an `Array` or `Seq` leads to **java.lang.ClassCastException**.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow

val row = InternalRow(Array(1, 2, 3), 1L)
println(s"Row first element: ${row.getArray(0).toIntArray.toVector}")
println(s"Row second element: ${row.getLong(1)}")
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayData
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getArray(rows.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getArray(rows.scala:195)
```

I solved this by passing an `ArrayData` field instead of `Array` or `Seq`. I used the `ArrayData.toArrayData` method as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayData

val row = InternalRow(ArrayData.toArrayData(Array(1, 2, 3)), 1L)
println(s"Row first element: ${row.getArray(0).toIntArray.toVector}")
println(s"Row second element: ${row.getLong(1)}")
```

```
Row first element: Vector(1, 2, 3)
Row second element: 1
```